# HTML textarea with minimum words condition

Tags: textarea, words, minimum

I am looking for a textarea code that allows users to submit the form only when they write a certain number of words (say 300) in the textarea provided. In-case anyone writes lesser number of words and tries to submit the form a warning message should show up.

I tried this code based on the suggestion below but the form is still getting submitted without any warning even for three-four words. Please help.

```html
<html>
<form action="articlesuccess.php" method="POST">
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkWordCount(){
    s = document.getElementById("article").value;
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    if (s.split(' ').length <= 300) {
        alarm("not enough words...");
    }
}
</script>
     
<p>
 
        <label for="article">Write the article in the box below:</label> <br/>
  <textarea name="article" id="article" style="width:700px; height:500px;"></textarea>
 
    </p>
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" onclick="checkWordCount()" value="Submit" /><input type="Reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think pure html code cannot achieve your desired goal. Instead, you need to write some javascript code. Suppose your textarea has an id attribute which is set as "inputString". Then the core of javascript code will be:

```
function checkWordCount(){
    s = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    if (s.split(' ').length <= 300) {
        alarm("not enough words...");
    }
}
```

And don't forget to wire the OnClick event of the submit button with this function. Let me know if I need to specify more.

The code is borrowed from http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/text/count-words.html

I have tweaked the code a bit and it is now working.
Here is an example based on the code after adjustments -

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkWordCount(){
    s = document.getElementById("article").value;
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    if (s.split(' ').length <= 300) {
        alert("not enough words...");
return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="nextdestination.php" method="POST">
<p>
 
        <label for="article">Write the article in the box below:</label> <br/>
  <textarea name="article" id="article" style="width:500px; height:400px;"></textarea>
 
    </p>
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" onclick="return checkWordCount()" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<textarea id="txtId">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.</textarea>
<span id="charsLeft"></span> characters left.
<button id="btnId" onclick="myFunction()">submit</button>
<script>
$('#txtId').limit('300','#charsLeft');
function myFunction(){
if($('#txtId').val().length< 300){
alert('not enough words... minimum limit 300');
}   
    else{
    alert('submit successfully');
}
} 
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthar/4kS65/1120/)

Comment: Your code is for number of characters. I want to validate the minimum number of words. Please give the code for minimum words in textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I hate error messages! I rather prefer a much more user friendly guiding messages. Give it a try and if you still prefer to have an error message I will make the necessary changes

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#text').keyup(function() {
    var currentWordCount = $("#text").val().match(/\S+/g).length;

    if (currentWordCount > 10) {
      $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('#wordcounter').html(10 - currentWordCount + ' more words to go!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea><span id="wordcounter"></span>
  <p>
    <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06cqrfcy/)

Comment: Ya this is working, but there are few issues. The form was not submitting until I changed the attribute of submit from type="button" to type="submit". And another important issue is that once the user inputs more than 300 words, the submit button gets active and it remains active even if the user deletes some text and the form is submitted even for lesser than 300 words. It would be better if the button gets deactivated again once the user deletes some of the content and makes it lesser than 300 words.

Comment: I want to prohibit the user from submitting the text lesser than the requisite number of words. If you have any suggestion, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum Minimum Words

Quick example inspired by @Vadims code :

HTML code:

```
<label>Content <span id="alert-textarea">*</span></label>
<form>
    <textarea id="textarea"> </textarea>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

JQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var minimumwords = 3;
var maximumwords = 7;

$('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    
  $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
    var currentWordCount = $("#textarea").val().match(/\S+/g).length;

if (currentWordCount > minimumwords) {
  $("button[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
  $('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    
    if(currentWordCount < minimumwords){
        $('#alert-textarea').html( 'Add ' + (minimumwords - currentWordCount) + ' Minimum Words To Be Able To Submit Listing');
    } else {
        $('#alert-textarea').html('*');
    }

}


if (currentWordCount < maximumwords) {
  $("button[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
  $('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    
    if(currentWordCount > maximumwords){
        $('#alert-textarea').html( 'Remove' + (maximumwords - currentWordCount) + ' Words To Be Able To Submit Listing');
    } else {
        $('#alert-textarea').html('*');
    }

}

 });
});
```